Game ad on television about a racing game with an environment that can be changed
When I was younger, I saw an ad on television, most likely on Jetix or Disney XD between 2008 and 2012. This video game ad was about a racing game where you could drive cars and where buildings could be destroyed. It was heavily marketed as a game where the environment could be changed, and every time you play again, the environment starts where they were left the last time you played. I believe this game was made for PC. What game was this?

Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Were there any science fiction aspects to this game?  Can you describe them?   A work must be on-topic to ask about it here.

Split/Second (2009)...? I haven't played it, but it doesn't look on-topic to me.

"Developer: Black Rock Studio" almost seems like a callback to Lost.

I’m voting to close this question because it isn't about science fiction or fantasy

This sounds like Split/Second: Velocity, a video game released in 2010. It was published by Disney Interactive Studios, hence why you would have seen adverts for it on Jetix and Disney XD. The game's central mechanic is "Power Plays", which can be activated at various points around each race track to wipe out opposing racers; strong enough Power Plays can alter the track's layout, creating or destroying shortcuts.




Did this game have sci-fi elements?

It feels science-fiction-y, but honestly I'm not sure it's any more science-fictional than the tech seen in the James Bond films, which are explicitly off-topic here IIRC.
